# Why cannot call 'select' recursively for Linux nonblocking socket

Tags: c, linux, recursion

I am working on implementing a non-blocking UDP socket on Linux using the 'old-school' SELECT. Basically, I have a thread that is running the following function:

```
int NBRecv(void* pv, size_t len){
    int res = -1;
    FD_ZERO(&select_socks);    
    FD_SET(sock, &select_socks);
    int readsocks = select(sock + 1, &select_socks, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, &select_timeout);
    assert(readsocks >= 0);
    if(readsocks == 0)
        return NBRecv(pv, len);
    else {
        if(FD_ISSET(sock, &select_socks)){
            res = read(sock, pv, len);
        }
        else
            res = 0;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Above there you see that I am calling the function again if no socket is available for read to keep on waiting (I am aware that this is an infinite loop). However, I got a segmentation error each time running this function (specifically, when running the recursive call). After removing the recursive call, everything works fine.

My naive understanding is that the recursion here is no different from a while loop.

So could anyone help me with why this error is happening?

Comment: You should use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) & read about [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)

Comment: 1) Where does select_timeout stem from? 2) select returning -1 is not necessarily an error, first check errno before throwing the crawbar.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for that! I'll look into poll and more recent non-blocking socket functions. I am using select here because we have a fairly small number of connections.

Comment: @wildplasser: Also select_socks. (And socks, but noone takes the address of socks). As for select returning -1, I think technically EINTR is an error but it is certainly not worth asserting over.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks. I'll find a better way to handle the return values. The timeout variable is a pre-defined timeval structure. I have actually changed it to a local variable of this function as I was told the select function modifies the timeval structure passed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike a while loop, recursion can<sup>†</sup> chew up stack space in proportion to the depth of the call stack. The more recursive calls, the more stack space used. Eventually your program runs out of stack space and crashes.

Use a while loop.

<sup><sup>†</sup> I say "can" because it's possible for [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to be optimized away, turning tail calls into simple jumps and eliminating the unbounded memory use. This is a special case; it's not applicable to all recursive calls. Nor can it be relied upon as the C language places no requirements on compilers to perform tail call elimination.</sup>

Comment: At -O2, gcc does Tail Call Optimization for the posted code. Of course, there is no guarantee, C is not Scheme.